# replace words in two columns from last line

Tags: string, bash, replace

I have a file and each column has between another column at least one space.

```
abc dogdogdogdog      1.0
abc cat               2.4
```

and now i want to double last line and change second and third columns but spaces layout should stay the same.

result:

```
abc dogdogdogdog      1.0
abc cat               2.4
abc elephant          mystring
```

how to do it?
now i'm thinking about reading last line, but i don't know how to pass variable to awk because in awk i think it will be easy to change only some column.

```
line=$(tail -n 1 $file)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add your efforts whicb you have put in order to solve your problem in CODE TAGS and let us knwo then.

Comment: what if the `elephant` was a very long string? i.e. longer than `dogdogdogdog` + 50 spaces? should 1st and 2nd row be changed as well? or you garantee that the new col2 will always fit the gap?

Comment: it won't be that long, i'm sure that it always be shorter than other strings in that coulmn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.(fair warning: tested with only given example)

```
awk -v line="abc elephant my_string" '
BEGIN{
  split(line,array," ")
}
match($0,/ .* +/) && FNR==1{
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/[a-zA-Z]+/," ",val)
}
1;
END{
  print array[1],array[2],substr(val,length(array[2]+1)),array[3]
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

> it won't be that long, I'm sure that it always be shorter than other strings in that column.

With OP's comment, this gawk one-liner should help (gawk required):

```
awk '7;END{n=gensub(/\S+(\s+)\S+$/,"new\\1mystring","g");print n}' file
```

With the given example:

```
kent$  cat f
abc dogdogdogdog      1.0
abc cat               2.4

kent$  awk '7;END{n=gensub(/\S+(\s+)\S+$/,"new\\1mystring","g");print n}' f
abc dogdogdogdog      1.0
abc cat               2.4
abc new               mystring
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda sparse, so...
Manual code - you can extrapolate to something programmatic.

```
$: cat 3col
abc dogdogdogdog      1.0
abc cat               2.4

$: read c1 x <<< $( tail -1 3col ) # read 1st column, throw the rest away
$: printf "%-4s%-18s%s\n" $c1 elephant mystring >> 3col # append col 1 and new values

$: $: cat 3col
abc dogdogdogdog      1.0
abc cat               2.4
abc elephant          mystring
```

If you want that in one line -

```
 printf "%-4s%-18s%-3s\n" $( sed -n '${s/ .*//;p;}' 3col ) elephant mystring >> 3col
```

That `sed` just prints the first column of the last line and throws away everything else.

Note that this doesn't technically *change* the last two columns - it keeps the first one and replaces the rest with the literals you specified.

If this doesn't handle what you need, consider that you might be posing an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and just rewrite your original question to say what you are trying to accomplish.